# Docker with WSL, without docker desktop

Tags: docker, powershell

I'm trying to install docker with Windows subsystem for linux 2, without docker desktop.

My ultimate goal is, windows powershell as docker client, wsl 2 ubuntu (22.04.3) as docker daemon.

Current steps :

1. I downloaded docker.exe, dockerd.exe in D:\Downloads\docker-25.0.1, and I added this folder to environment variables.
2. sudo update-alternatives --config iptables  -> choose 'iptables-legacy'
3. I updated /usr/sbin/systemctl file, so I can use systemctl command in wsl.

What is different between

1. sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/docker.service   -> change 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H 0.0.0.0:2375'

   - small question : Now I'm using docker version 25.0.1, ubuntu 22.04.3. Many documents said I need to use 'systemctl daemon-reload' after update docker.service, but I got 'daemon-reload: unrecognized service'. Is this command deprecated?
2. sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json -> add {"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]}

When I try number 2, everything is fine. But when I try number 1, 'docker ps' command from windows powershell and wsl2 ubuntu is not working. (Also, 'sudo lsof -i' shows nothing.) But 'sudo docker ps' is working, even though I logged in by root!
I want to know the reason why.
Thanks.